# How printf statement works in the below code?

Tags: c

```
void main()
{
printf("Adi%d"+2,3);
}
```

output= i3

This printf statement worked, but how the statement worked ?

Comment: This is not an example to follow.

Comment: Now why does this work? `printf(&2??("Adi%d" :> ,010-05);` Same kind of pointless obfuscation question.

Comment: Note [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Answer (score 8):

```
printf("Adi%d"+2,3);
```

`"Adi%d"` - is interpreted as start of the address of the memory where the string literal `"Adi%d"` is stored. When you add 2 to it, it became address of memory where string `"i%d"` is stored. So basically you passed to printf string: `"i%d"`. Then `%d` and `printf` came into play replacing `%d` with 3, hence the output `i3`.

Answer (score 1):

Its part of pointer to character, nothing to do with printf, `"Adi" + 2` will  make it read from position `0 + 2 = 2` that will be `i`

```
int main()
{
    char* a = "Adi" + 2;
    printf(a); // output i

}
```